# Cannot open second JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

In my application, I need to open 2 JFileChooser in sequence (to select source files and target directory). The second one simply never shows up... I boiled down the code to the absolute minimum, still does not work:

```
public class FileChooserTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create main window
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame( "Import Pictures");
        mainFrame.setSize( 1000, 500 );
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        JFileChooser inputChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = inputChooser.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);

        JFileChooser outputChooser = new JFileChooser();
        returnVal = outputChooser.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
    }

}
```

The application hangs in the "showOpenDialog" call of the "outputChooser"...

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_181, NetBeans 8.2, Mac OS X Mojave Beta.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: That code works as expected, here, despite not being started on the EDT. I suggest you fix that first, then check the [Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/).

Comment: works here as well, Windows, though

Answer (score 0):

You could try to not use `returnVal` for both of the file choosers.

```
JFileChooser inputChooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal1 = inputChooser.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);

JFileChooser outputChooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal2 = outputChooser.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
```

I do not have my computer with me right now so I can not test that to see if it works, but it seems like f they are both being opened on the same return value then one of them probably wont open up. Try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: When you open a file chooser the `showOpenDialog(mainFrame)` returns an `int` but it also opens the dialog box, if you do it with the same value `returnValue` then it is only going to open one dialog box because it can only return the result to one `int`